# SimpleSAMLphp Configuration Misconfiguration Error

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, simplesamlphp

I am installing SAML in PHP using the SimpleSAMLphp extension with ADFS.

I have installed SAML, and I have configured sp and idp, but I am getting an error something like below:

```
    SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION

Backtrace:
0 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:180 (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Missing <saml:NameID> or <saml:EncryptedID> in <saml:Subject>.
Backtrace:
7 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/lib/SAML2/Assertion.php:262 (SAML2_Assertion::parseSubject)
6 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/lib/SAML2/Assertion.php:235 (SAML2_Assertion::__construct)
5 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/lib/SAML2/EncryptedAssertion.php:93 (SAML2_EncryptedAssertion::getAssertion)
4 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:355 (sspmod_saml_Message::decryptAssertion)
3 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:554 (sspmod_saml_Message::processAssertion)
2 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/Message.php:528 (sspmod_saml_Message::processResponse)
1 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:81 (require)
0 /home/aephradmprod/app/httpd/mhtdocs/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:135 (N/A)
```

**config/config.php**

```
<?php
```

/* 
 * The configuration of simpleSAMLphp
 * 
 * $Id: config.php 3246 2013-05-23 11:43:52Z olavmrk $
 */

$config = array (

```
/**
 * Setup the following parameters to match the directory of your installation.
 * See the user manual for more details.
 *
 * Valid format for baseurlpath is:
 * [(http|https)://(hostname|fqdn)[:port]]/[path/to/simplesaml/]
 * (note that it must end with a '/')
 *
 * The full url format is useful if your simpleSAMLphp setup is hosted behind
 * a reverse proxy. In that case you can specify the external url here.
 *
 * Please note that simpleSAMLphp will then redirect all queries to the
 * external url, no matter where you come from (direct access or via the
 * reverse proxy).
 */
// 'baseurlpath'           => 'simplesaml/',
'baseurlpath'           => 'https://mydomain/simplesaml/',
'certdir'               => 'cert/',
'loggingdir'            => 'log/',
'datadir'               => 'data/',

/*
 * A directory where simpleSAMLphp can save temporary files.
 *
 * SimpleSAMLphp will attempt to create this directory if it doesn't exist.
 */
'tempdir'               => '/tmp/simplesaml',


/*
 * If you enable this option, simpleSAMLphp will log all sent and received messages
 * to the log file.
 *
 * This option also enables logging of the messages that are encrypted and decrypted.
 *
 * Note: The messages are logged with the DEBUG log level, so you also need to set
 * the 'logging.level' option to LOG_DEBUG.
 */
'debug' => FALSE,


'showerrors'            =>  TRUE,

/**
 * Custom error show function called from SimpleSAML_Error_Error::show.
 * See docs/simplesamlphp-errorhandling.txt for function code example.
 *
 * Example:
 *   'errors.show_function' => array('sspmod_example_Error_Show', 'show'),
 */

/**
 * This option allows you to enable validation of XML data against its
 * schemas. A warning will be written to the log if validation fails.
 */
'debug.validatexml' => FALSE,

/**
 * This password must be kept secret, and modified from the default value 123.
 * This password will give access to the installation page of simpleSAMLphp with
 * metadata listing and diagnostics pages.
 * You can also put a hash here; run "bin/pwgen.php" to generate one.
 */
'auth.adminpassword'        => 'xxxxxxx',
'admin.protectindexpage'    => false,
'admin.protectmetadata'     => false,

/**
 * This is a secret salt used by simpleSAMLphp when it needs to generate a secure hash
 * of a value. It must be changed from its default value to a secret value. The value of
 * 'secretsalt' can be any valid string of any length.
 *
 * A possible way to generate a random salt is by running the following command from a unix shell:
 * tr -c -d '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' </dev/urandom | dd bs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null;echo
 */
'secretsalt' => 'j6fbg3kxmelivp2qmy1uj8y0j8ucp903',

/*
 * Some information about the technical persons running this installation.
 * The email address will be used as the recipient address for error reports, and
 * also as the technical contact in generated metadata.
 */
'technicalcontact_name'     => 'Myconnect Admin',
'technicalcontact_email'    => 'admin@gmail.com',

/*
 * The timezone of the server. This option should be set to the timezone you want
 * simpleSAMLphp to report the time in. The default is to guess the timezone based
 * on your system timezone.
 *
 * See this page for a list of valid timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
 */
'timezone' => 'Asia/Calcutta',

/*
 * Logging.
 * 
 * define the minimum log level to log
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::ERR      No statistics, only errors
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::WARNING  No statistics, only warnings/errors
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::NOTICE   Statistics and errors
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::INFO     Verbose logs
 *      SimpleSAML_Logger::DEBUG    Full debug logs - not reccomended for production
 * 
 * Choose logging handler.
 * 
 * Options: [syslog,file,errorlog]
 * 
 */
'logging.level'         => SimpleSAML_Logger::NOTICE,
'logging.handler'       => 'syslog',

/*
 * Choose which facility should be used when logging with syslog.
 *
 * These can be used for filtering the syslog output from simpleSAMLphp into its
 * own file by configuring the syslog daemon.
 *
 * See the documentation for openlog (http://php.net/manual/en/function.openlog.php) for available
 * facilities. Note that only LOG_USER is valid on windows.
 *
 * The default is to use LOG_LOCAL5 if available, and fall back to LOG_USER if not.
 */
'logging.facility' => defined('LOG_LOCAL5') ? constant('LOG_LOCAL5') : LOG_USER,

/*
 * The process name that should be used when logging to syslog.
 * The value is also written out by the other logging handlers.
 */
'logging.processname' => 'simplesamlphp',

/* Logging: file - Logfilename in the loggingdir from above.
 */
'logging.logfile'       => 'simplesamlphp.log',

/* (New) statistics output configuration.
 *
 * This is an array of outputs. Each output has at least a 'class' option, which
 * selects the output.
 */
'statistics.out' => array(
    // Log statistics to the normal log.
    /*
    array(
        'class' => 'core:Log',
        'level' => 'notice',
    ),
    */
    // Log statistics to files in a directory. One file per day.
    /*
    array(
        'class' => 'core:File',
        'directory' => '/var/log/stats',
    ),
    */
),


/*
 * Enable
 * 
 * Which functionality in simpleSAMLphp do you want to enable. Normally you would enable only 
 * one of the functionalities below, but in some cases you could run multiple functionalities.
 * In example when you are setting up a federation bridge.
 */
'enable.saml20-idp'     => true,
'enable.shib13-idp'     => false,
'enable.adfs-idp'       => true,
'enable.wsfed-sp'       => false,
'enable.authmemcookie' => false,


/*
 * Module enable configuration
 *
 * Configuration to override module enabling/disabling.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * 'module.enable' => array(
 *  // Setting to TRUE enables.
 *  'exampleauth' => TRUE,
 *  // Setting to FALSE disables.
 *  'saml' => FALSE,
 *  // Unset or NULL uses default.
 *  'core' => NULL,
 * ),
 *
 */


/* 
 * This value is the duration of the session in seconds. Make sure that the time duration of
 * cookies both at the SP and the IdP exceeds this duration.
 */
'session.duration'      =>  8 * (60*60), // 8 hours.

/*
 * Sets the duration, in seconds, data should be stored in the datastore. As the datastore is used for
 * login and logout requests, thid option will control the maximum time these operations can take.
 * The default is 4 hours (4*60*60) seconds, which should be more than enough for these operations.
 */
'session.datastore.timeout' => (4*60*60), // 4 hours

/*
 * Sets the duration, in seconds, auth state should be stored.
 */
'session.state.timeout' => (60*60), // 1 hour

/*
 * Option to override the default settings for the session cookie name
 */
'session.cookie.name' => 'SimpleSAMLSessionID',

/*
 * Expiration time for the session cookie, in seconds.
 *
 * Defaults to 0, which means that the cookie expires when the browser is closed.
 *
 * Example:
 *  'session.cookie.lifetime' => 30*60,
 */
'session.cookie.lifetime' => 0,

/*
 * Limit the path of the cookies.
 *
 * Can be used to limit the path of the cookies to a specific subdirectory.
 *
 * Example:
 *  'session.cookie.path' => '/simplesaml/',
 */
'session.cookie.path' => '/',

/*
 * Cookie domain.
 *
 * Can be used to make the session cookie available to several domains.
 *
 * Example:
 *  'session.cookie.domain' => '.example.org',
 */
'session.cookie.domain' => NULL,

/*
 * Set the secure flag in the cookie.
 *
 * Set this to TRUE if the user only accesses your service
 * through https. If the user can access the service through
 * both http and https, this must be set to FALSE.
 */
'session.cookie.secure' => FALSE,

/*
 * When set to FALSE fallback to transient session on session initialization
 * failure, throw exception otherwise.
 */
'session.disable_fallback' => FALSE,

/*
 * Enable secure POST from HTTPS to HTTP.
 *
 * If you have some SP's on HTTP and IdP is normally on HTTPS, this option
 * enables secure POSTing to HTTP endpoint without warning from browser.
 *
 * For this to work, module.php/core/postredirect.php must be accessible
 * also via HTTP on IdP, e.g. if your IdP is on
 * https://idp.example.org/ssp/, then
 * http://idp.example.org/ssp/module.php/core/postredirect.php must be accessible.
 */
'enable.http_post' => FALSE,

/*
 * Options to override the default settings for php sessions.
 */
'session.phpsession.cookiename'  => null,
'session.phpsession.savepath'    => null,
'session.phpsession.httponly'    => FALSE,

/*
 * Option to override the default settings for the auth token cookie
 */
'session.authtoken.cookiename' => 'SimpleSAMLAuthToken',

/*
 * Languages available, RTL languages, and what language is default
 */
'language.available'    => array('en', 'no', 'nn', 'se', 'da', 'de', 'sv', 'fi', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'nl', 'lb', 'cs', 'sl', 'lt', 'hr', 'hu', 'pl', 'pt', 'pt-br', 'tr', 'ja', 'zh', 'zh-tw', 'ru', 'et', 'he', 'id', 'sr', 'lv'),
'language.rtl'      => array('ar','dv','fa','ur','he'),
'language.default'      => 'en',

/*
 * Options to override the default settings for the language parameter
 */
'language.parameter.name'   => 'language',
'language.parameter.setcookie'  => TRUE,

/*
 * Options to override the default settings for the language cookie
 */
'language.cookie.name'      => 'language',
'language.cookie.domain'        => NULL,
'language.cookie.path'      => '/',
'language.cookie.lifetime'      => (60*60*24*900),

/**
 * Custom getLanguage function called from SimpleSAML_XHTML_Template::getLanguage().
 * Function should return language code of one of the available languages or NULL.
 * See SimpleSAML_XHTML_Template::getLanguage() source code for more info.
 *
 * This option can be used to implement a custom function for determining
 * the default language for the user.
 *
 * Example:
 *   'language.get_language_function' => array('sspmod_example_Template', 'getLanguage'),
 */

/*
 * Extra dictionary for attribute names.
 * This can be used to define local attributes.
 *
 * The format of the parameter is a string with <module>:<dictionary>.
 *
 * Specifying this option will cause us to look for modules/<module>/dictionaries/<dictionary>.definition.json
 * The dictionary should look something like:
 *
 * {
 *     "firstattribute": {
 *         "en": "English name",
 *         "no": "Norwegian name"
 *     },
 *     "secondattribute": {
 *         "en": "English name",
 *         "no": "Norwegian name"
 *     }
 * }
 *
 * Note that all attribute names in the dictionary must in lowercase.
 *
 * Example: 'attributes.extradictionary' => 'ourmodule:ourattributes',
 */
'attributes.extradictionary' => NULL,

/*
 * Which theme directory should be used?
 */
'theme.use'         => 'default',


/*
 * Default IdP for WS-Fed.
 */
'default-wsfed-idp' => 'urn:federation:pingfederate:localhost',

/*
 * Whether the discovery service should allow the user to save his choice of IdP.
 */
'idpdisco.enableremember' => TRUE,
'idpdisco.rememberchecked' => TRUE,

// Disco service only accepts entities it knows.
'idpdisco.validate' => TRUE,

'idpdisco.extDiscoveryStorage' => NULL, 

/*
 * IdP Discovery service look configuration. 
 * Wether to display a list of idp or to display a dropdown box. For many IdP' a dropdown box  
 * gives the best use experience.
 * 
 * When using dropdown box a cookie is used to highlight the previously chosen IdP in the dropdown.  
 * This makes it easier for the user to choose the IdP
 * 
 * Options: [links,dropdown]
 * 
 */
'idpdisco.layout' => 'dropdown',

/*
 * Whether simpleSAMLphp should sign the response or the assertion in SAML 1.1 authentication
 * responses.
 *
 * The default is to sign the assertion element, but that can be overridden by setting this
 * option to TRUE. It can also be overridden on a pr. SP basis by adding an option with the
 * same name to the metadata of the SP.
 */
'shib13.signresponse' => TRUE,



/*
 * Authentication processing filters that will be executed for all IdPs
 * Both Shibboleth and SAML 2.0
 */
'authproc.idp' => array(
    /* Enable the authproc filter below to add URN Prefixces to all attributes
    10 => array(
        'class' => 'core:AttributeMap', 'addurnprefix'
    ), */
    /* Enable the authproc filter below to automatically generated eduPersonTargetedID. 
    20 => 'core:TargetedID',
    */

    // Adopts language from attribute to use in UI
    30 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',

    /* Add a realm attribute from edupersonprincipalname
    40 => 'core:AttributeRealm',
     */
    45 => array(
        'class' => 'core:StatisticsWithAttribute',
        'attributename' => 'realm',
        'type' => 'saml20-idp-SSO',
    ),

    /* When called without parameters, it will fallback to filter attributes ‹the old way›
     * by checking the 'attributes' parameter in metadata on IdP hosted and SP remote.
     */
    50 => 'core:AttributeLimit', 

    /* 
     * Search attribute "distinguishedName" for pattern and replaces if found

    60 => array(
        'class'     => 'core:AttributeAlter',
        'pattern'   => '/OU=studerende/',
        'replacement'   => 'Student',
        'subject'   => 'distinguishedName',
        '%replace', 
    ),
     */

    /*
     * Consent module is enabled (with no permanent storage, using cookies).

    90 => array(
        'class'     => 'consent:Consent', 
        'store'     => 'consent:Cookie', 
        'focus'     => 'yes', 
        'checked'   => TRUE
    ),
     */
    // If language is set in Consent module it will be added as an attribute.
    99 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',
),
/*
 * Authentication processing filters that will be executed for all SPs
 * Both Shibboleth and SAML 2.0
 */
'authproc.sp' => array(
    /*
    10 => array(
        'class' => 'core:AttributeMap', 'removeurnprefix'
    ),
    */

    /*
     * Generate the 'group' attribute populated from other variables, including eduPersonAffiliation.
     */
    60 => array('class' => 'core:GenerateGroups', 'eduPersonAffiliation'),
    // All users will be members of 'users' and 'members'   
    61 => array('class' => 'core:AttributeAdd', 'groups' => array('users', 'members')),

    // Adopts language from attribute to use in UI
    90 => 'core:LanguageAdaptor',

),


/*
 * This option configures the metadata sources. The metadata sources is given as an array with
 * different metadata sources. When searching for metadata, simpleSAMPphp will search through
 * the array from start to end.
 *
 * Each element in the array is an associative array which configures the metadata source.
 * The type of the metadata source is given by the 'type' element. For each type we have
 * different configuration options.
 *
 * Flat file metadata handler:
 * - 'type': This is always 'flatfile'.
 * - 'directory': The directory we will load the metadata files from. The default value for
 *                this option is the value of the 'metadatadir' configuration option, or
 *                'metadata/' if that option is unset.
 *
 * XML metadata handler:
 * This metadata handler parses an XML file with either an EntityDescriptor element or an
 * EntitiesDescriptor element. The XML file may be stored locally, or (for debugging) on a remote
 * web server.
 * The XML hetadata handler defines the following options:
 * - 'type': This is always 'xml'.
 * - 'file': Path to the XML file with the metadata.
 * - 'url': The url to fetch metadata from. THIS IS ONLY FOR DEBUGGING - THERE IS NO CACHING OF THE RESPONSE.
 *
 *
 * Examples:
 *
 * This example defines two flatfile sources. One is the default metadata directory, the other
 * is a metadata directory with autogenerated metadata files.
 *
 * 'metadata.sources' => array(
 *     array('type' => 'flatfile'),
 *     array('type' => 'flatfile', 'directory' => 'metadata-generated'),
 *     ),
 *
 * This example defines a flatfile source and an XML source.
 * 'metadata.sources' => array(
 *     array('type' => 'flatfile'),
 *     array('type' => 'xml', 'file' => 'idp.example.org-idpMeta.xml'),
 *     ),
 *
 *
 * Default:
 * 'metadata.sources' => array(
 *     array('type' => 'flatfile')
 *     ),
 */
'metadata.sources' => array(
    array('type' => 'flatfile'),
),


/*
 * Configure the datastore for simpleSAMLphp.
 *
 * - 'phpsession': Limited datastore, which uses the PHP session.
 * - 'memcache': Key-value datastore, based on memcache.
 * - 'sql': SQL datastore, using PDO.
 *
 * The default datastore is 'phpsession'.
 *
 * (This option replaces the old 'session.handler'-option.)
 */
'store.type' => 'phpsession',


/*
 * The DSN the sql datastore should connect to.
 *
 * See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php for the various
 * syntaxes.
 */
'store.sql.dsn' => 'sqlite:/path/to/sqlitedatabase.sq3',

/*
 * The username and password to use when connecting to the database.
 */
'store.sql.username' => NULL,
'store.sql.password' => NULL,

/*
 * The prefix we should use on our tables.
 */
'store.sql.prefix' => 'simpleSAMLphp',


/*
 * Configuration for the MemcacheStore class. This allows you to store
 * multiple redudant copies of sessions on different memcache servers.
 *
 * 'memcache_store.servers' is an array of server groups. Every data
 * item will be mirrored in every server group.
 *
 * Each server group is an array of servers. The data items will be
 * load-balanced between all servers in each server group.
 *
 * Each server is an array of parameters for the server. The following
 * options are available:
 *  - 'hostname': This is the hostname or ip address where the
 *    memcache server runs. This is the only required option.
 *  - 'port': This is the port number of the memcache server. If this
 *    option isn't set, then we will use the 'memcache.default_port'
 *    ini setting. This is 11211 by default.
 *  - 'weight': This sets the weight of this server in this server
 *    group. http://php.net/manual/en/function.Memcache-addServer.php
 *    contains more information about the weight option.
 *  - 'timeout': The timeout for this server. By default, the timeout
 *    is 3 seconds.
 *
 * Example of redudant configuration with load balancing:
 * This configuration makes it possible to lose both servers in the
 * a-group or both servers in the b-group without losing any sessions.
 * Note that sessions will be lost if one server is lost from both the
 * a-group and the b-group.
 *
 * 'memcache_store.servers' => array(
 *     array(
 *         array('hostname' => 'mc_a1'),
 *         array('hostname' => 'mc_a2'),
 *     ),
 *     array(
 *         array('hostname' => 'mc_b1'),
 *         array('hostname' => 'mc_b2'),
 *     ),
 * ),
 *
 * Example of simple configuration with only one memcache server,
 * running on the same computer as the web server:
 * Note that all sessions will be lost if the memcache server crashes.
 *
 * 'memcache_store.servers' => array(
 *     array(
 *         array('hostname' => 'localhost'),
 *     ),
 * ),
 *
 */
'memcache_store.servers' => array(
    array(
        array('hostname' => 'localhost'),
    ),
),


/*
 * This value is the duration data should be stored in memcache. Data
 * will be dropped from the memcache servers when this time expires.
 * The time will be reset every time the data is written to the
 * memcache servers.
 *
 * This value should always be larger than the 'session.duration'
 * option. Not doing this may result in the session being deleted from
 * the memcache servers while it is still in use.
 *
 * Set this value to 0 if you don't want data to expire.
 *
 * Note: The oldest data will always be deleted if the memcache server
 * runs out of storage space.
 */
'memcache_store.expires' =>  36 * (60*60), // 36 hours.


/*
 * Should signing of generated metadata be enabled by default.
 *
 * Metadata signing can also be enabled for a individual SP or IdP by setting the
 * same option in the metadata for the SP or IdP.
 */
'metadata.sign.enable' => FALSE,

/*
 * The default key & certificate which should be used to sign generated metadata. These
 * are files stored in the cert dir.
 * These values can be overridden by the options with the same names in the SP or
 * IdP metadata.
 *
 * If these aren't specified here or in the metadata for the SP or IdP, then
 * the 'certificate' and 'privatekey' option in the metadata will be used.
 * if those aren't set, signing of metadata will fail.
 */
'metadata.sign.privatekey' => NULL,
'metadata.sign.privatekey_pass' => NULL,
'metadata.sign.certificate' => NULL,


/*
 * Proxy to use for retrieving URLs.
 *
 * Example:
 *   'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy.example.com:5100'
 */
'proxy' => NULL,

/*
 * Array of URL's to allow a trusted redirect to.
 *
 * Set to NULL to disable.
 *
 * Example:
 *   'redirect.trustedsites' => array('sp.example.com', 'othersite.org'),
 */
'redirect.trustedsites' => NULL,
```

);

**config/authsources.php**

```
<?php
```

$config = array(

```
// This is a authentication source which handles admin authentication.
'admin' => array(
    // The default is to use core:AdminPassword, but it can be replaced with
    // any authentication source.

    'core:AdminPassword',
),


// An authentication source which can authenticate against both SAML 2.0
// and Shibboleth 1.3 IdPs.
'default-sp' => array(
    'saml:SP',
    'privatekey'=>'saml.pem',
    'certificate' =>'saml.crt',

    //'RelayState' => 'https://www.google.co.in/',

    // The entity ID of this SP.
    // Can be NULL/unset, in which case an entity ID is generated based on the metadata URL.
    'entityID' => NULL,

    // The entity ID of the IdP this should SP should contact.
    // Can be NULL/unset, in which case the user will be shown a list of available IdPs.
     'idp' => NULL,
    //'idp' => 'http://adfsfusion.axisbank.com/adfs/services/trust',

    // The URL to the discovery service.
    // Can be NULL/unset, in which case a builtin discovery service will be used.
    'discoURL' => NULL,
    //'NameIDPolicy' => null,
    'attributes' => array('SamAccountName','E-MailAddress','Name'),
    'signature.algorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256&#8217;',
    'assertion.encryption' => true,
),
```

**metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php**

```
$metadata['__DYNAMIC:1__'] = array(
    /*
     * The hostname of the server (VHOST) that will use this SAML entity.
     *
     * Can be '__DEFAULT__', to use this entry by default.
     */
    'host' => '__DEFAULT__',

    /* X.509 key and certificate. Relative to the cert directory. */
    'privatekey' => 'saml.pem',
    'certificate' => 'saml.crt',

    /*
     * Authentication source to use. Must be one that is configured in
     * 'config/authsources.php'.
     */
    'auth' => 'example-userpass',

    /* Uncomment the following to use the uri NameFormat on attributes. */

    'attributes.NameFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri',
    'authproc' => array(
        // Convert LDAP names to oids.
        100 => array('class' => 'core:AttributeMap', 'name2oid'),
    ),


);
```

**metadata/saml20-sp-remote.php**

```
$metadata['https://example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp'] = array(
    'AssertionConsumerService' => 'https://example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
    //'AssertionConsumerService' => 'https://adfs.com/adfs/services/trust/mex',
    // 'SingleLogoutService' => 'https://saml2sp.example.org/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp',
    // 'attributes' => array('emp_id','emp_name')
);

/*

 */
$metadata['google.com'] = array(
    'AssertionConsumerService' => 'https://www.google.com/a/g.feide.no/acs',
    'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress',
    'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'uid',
    'simplesaml.attributes' => FALSE,
);
```

**metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * SAML 2.0 remote IdP metadata for simpleSAMLphp.
 *
 * Remember to remove the IdPs you don't use from this file.
 *
 * See: https://rnd.feide.no/content/idp-remote-metadata-reference
 */

/*
 * Guest IdP. allows users to sign up and register. Great for testing!
 */
$metadata['https://adfs-example.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml'] = array(
    'name' => array(
        'en' => 'Fusion',
        'no' => 'Feide Gjestebrukere',
    ),
    'description'          => 'desc',

    'SingleSignOnService'  => 'https://example.com/site/samlLogin',
    // 'SingleLogoutService'  => 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
    'certFingerprint'      => 'c9ed4dfb07caf13fc21e0fec1572047eb8a7a4cb'
);

//////////////////////////////////////////// configuration for idp - added by satyawan shinde ///////////
$metadata['http://adfs-example.com/adfs/services/trust'] = array (
  'entityid' => 'http://adfs-example.com/adfs/services/trust',
  'contacts' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'contactType' => 'support',
      'givenName' => 'Ganesh',
      'surName' => 'Chavan',
      'emailAddress' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Ganesh.Chavan@example.com',
      ),
      'telephoneNumber' => 
      array (
        0 => '1067',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
  'SingleSignOnService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'https://adfs-example.com/adfs/ls/',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
      'Location' => 'https://adfs-example.com/adfs/ls/',
    ),
  ),
  'SingleLogoutService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'https://adfs-example.com/adfs/ls/',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
      'Location' => 'https://adfs-example.com/adfs/ls/',
    ),
  ),
  'ArtifactResolutionService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP',
      'Location' => 'https://adfs-example.com/adfs/services/trust/artifactresolution',
      'index' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  'keys' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'encryption' => true,
      'signing' => false,
      'type' => 'X509Certificate',
      'X509Certificate' => 'ssl charactors',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'encryption' => false,
      'signing' => true,
      'type' => 'X509Certificate',
      'X509Certificate' => 'ssl certificate chars',
    ),
  ),
);
```

**here i have been posted all configuration code.**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is it even possible to answer this without any code?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: It seems like your IdP is not sending a NameId in the assertion. You can use a SAML tracer plugin for your browser to inspect the messages.

Comment: Okay, Thank you !!!!. i will try saml trace puglin.